# iPad: Custom Toolbar for UISplitViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

How exactly does one go about implementing a custom toolbar for the main table view section of a split view?

The program I am writing for the iPad is landscape only so the split view has a static table view along the left side, and at the top is the toolbar with a title. It is this toolbar I would like to change. I have created the split view controller, table view controller, and detail view controllers programmatically so I should have reference to the toolbar object. The only thing is I don't know how to reference it so I can overwrite it with my custom toolbar.

Is it the split view controller that creates this toolbar? Or the table view?

Any ideas?

Comment: BY "main table view", do you mean the "Master" view (left-side, disappears in portrait) or the "Detail" view (right-side, always present)?

Answer (score 0):

It's a navigation bar, not a toolbar. You'll want to investigate the `navigationItem` property of the UIViewController responsible for the view with the navigation bar. This is an instance of `UINavigationItem`; see the documentation here: [UINavigationItem](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UINavigationItem).